# Doxygen/C++ : how to link to anonymous namespace variables

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen to document my code.  Much of the code has anonymous namespaces in the cpp files where constants are defined.  I have set:

`EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES = YES`

in my Doxygen file and all anonymous namespaces are documented as desired.

My problem is that I want to reference a variable in an anonymous namespace.  For example, suppose one of the namespaces is defined in my Doxygen document under `MyClass::anonymous_namespace{MyFile.cpp}::kMyConstant`.  I figured that another comment block (say, for a function) could link to that constant like:

`@see MyClass::anonymous_namespace{MyFile.cpp}::kMyConstant`

Unfortunately the only link I get is to MyFile.cpp, but not through the anonymous namespace to the constant variable.  Obviously I want to do this so that if the value of the constant changes, the documentation will reference the new value when Doxygen is rerun.  Putting the explicit value of the constant in the documentation would be dangerous if the constant ever changes.

Is my format above incorrect?  I've searched for an answer for this extensively but to no avail.

Answer (score 7):

What you want hasn't been implemented yet, but I agree it is useful and the format you use is the right one and should work.

I'll implement this in the next release.

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt response.  I look forward to your next release.

Comment: Has this been ever implemented? What is the syntax? I don't find it in the docs...